# TimeSpan to DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I want to convert a Timespan to Datetime. How can I do this?

I found one method on Google:

```
DateTime dt;
TimeSpan ts="XXX";

//We can covnert 'ts' to 'dt' like this:

dt= Convert.ToDateTime(ts.ToString());
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you have a start point (which you will need), just add the timespan to the start date.

Comment: i don't have the starttime. The API which is exposed supports only the DateTime

Comment: If you dont have a start- or end-point, what you are trying to do is nonsensical.

Comment: How could you convert it without a starting point to reference?

Comment: TimeSpan is a duration it could be part of the `DateTime` or a indicative of the difference between two relevant `DateTime`, you gotta atleast know/assume something, what do you thing you can represent with `1 Hour timespan` ?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

It is not very logical to convert TimeSpan to DateTime. Try to understand what leppie said above. TimeSpan is a duration say 6 Days 5 Hours 40 minutes. It is not a Date. If I say 6 Days; Can you deduce a Date from it? The answer is NO unless you have a REFERENCE Date.

So if you want to convert TimeSpan to DateTime you need a reference date. 6 Days & 5 Hours from when? So you can write something like this:

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(2012, 01, 01);
 TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 dt = dt + ts;
```

Comment: Your answer is correct and I thank you ... but converting TimeSpan to DateTime _can_ be a logical, meaningful thing to do.  For example, Entity Framework maps the TSQL time type (which is time-of-day) to TimeSpan -- as duration since midnight.  To format the value, I want it as DateTime so I can use one of its formatter methods that excludes the date part ... Maybe EF should use DateTime instead, but I think it's at least somewhat reasonable to treat TimeSpan as duration since midnight and besides I can't change EF behavior.

Comment: I'm using DateTime.Today + ts to convert, then if you wanna format the time to display, it'll look good

Comment: Just tried ts + dt and got "+ operator cannot be applied" so be careful. The sum is not commutative.

Comment: sometimes it's logical, like in WPF app where you have TimePicker control that uses DateTime but you want timespan instead...

Comment: no reference date needed then because date is simply ignored, and you get only hour:minute part

Answer (score 37):

While the selected answer is strictly correct, I believe I understand what the OP is trying to get at here as I had a similar issue.

I had a TimeSpan which I wished to display in a grid control (as just hh:mm) but the grid didn't appear to understand TimeSpan, only DateTime .  The OP has a similar scenario where only the TimeSpan is the relevant part but didn't consider the necessity of adding the DateTime reference point.

So, as indicated above, I simply added DateTime.MinValue (though any date will do) which is subsequently ignored by the grid when it renders the timespan as a time portion of the resulting date.

Comment: That was exactly my use case as well, except in a chart. I needed to show the elapsed time in the X axis.

Answer (score 20):

TimeSpan can be added to a fresh DateTime to achieve this.

```
TimeSpan ts="XXX";
DateTime dt = new DateTime() + ts;
```

But as mentioned before, it is not strictly logical without a valid start date. I have encountered
a use-case where i required only the time aspect. will work fine as long as the logic is correct.

Answer (score 10):

You need a reference date for this to be useful.

An example from 
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add.aspx

```
// Calculate what day of the week is 36 days from this instant.  
System.DateTime today = System.DateTime.Now;  
System.TimeSpan duration = new System.TimeSpan(36, 0, 0, 0);  
System.DateTime answer = today.Add(duration);  
System.Console.WriteLine("{0:dddd}", answer);
```

Comment: Very useful function when returning a Time value from a database that needs to be displayed in a grid!

Answer (score 10):

Worked for me.

```
var StartTime = new DateTime(item.StartTime.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to show time value in a datagrid or label similar, best way is convert directly time in datetime datatype.

SELECT CONVERT(datetime,myTimeField) as myTimeField FROM Table1

Comment: If you licenses SQL by the core, then maybe let the application server perform this conversion and save the cycles.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use DateTime.FromFileTime(finishTime) where finishTme is a long containing the ticks of a time. Or FromFileTimeUtc.

Answer (score -2):

An easy method, use ticks:

```
new DateTime((DateTime.Now - DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1.55)).Ticks).ToString("HH:mm:ss:fff")
```

This function will give you a date (Without Day / Month / Year)

Comment: The OP wanted to convert a Timepan to a DateTime, your answer doesn't address that.

Comment: TIP: If you want a `DateTime` time part, just do `<DateTime>.TimeOfDay`. Similar to the date part, `<DateTime>.Date`.

Answer (score -3):

A problem with all of the above is that the conversion returns the incorrect number of days as specified in the TimeSpan.
Using the above, the below returns 3 and not 2.

Ideas on how to preserve the 2 days in the TimeSpan arguments and return them as the DateTime day?

```
public void should_return_totaldays()
{
    _ts = new TimeSpan(2, 1, 30, 10);
    var format = "dd";
    var returnedVal = _ts.ToString(format);
    Assert.That(returnedVal, Is.EqualTo("2")); //returns 3 not 2
}
```

Comment: The actual result when running your code is "02". The only remote explanation I can think is the _ts is not defined as a TimeSpan (you don't declare it in your snippit) but your comment in the code is incorrect.  When  _ts is declared as a TimeSpan, it returns the correct value for the days component of the duration.

Answer (score -4):

First, convert the timespan to a string, then to DateTime, then back to a string:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(timespan.SelectedTime.ToString()).ToShortTimeString();
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thing the OP suggested?  He was asking for methods other than converting to string first.

Comment: SelectedTime is not exists