# Binding ticks in a WebApi route parameter to DateTime

Tags: c#, rest, datetime, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I need milisecond precision on my DateTime object therefore I am sending Ticks from my Windows Service to my WebApi. This is my call to api, the last parameter is the datetime

> v1/Product/2/1/1000/636149434774700000

On the Api the request hits a controller that looks like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/Product/{site}/{start?}/{pageSize?}/{from?}")]
public IHttpActionResult Product(Site site, int start = 1, int pageSize = 100, DateTime? fromLastUpdated = null)
```

Default model binder fails to bind the ticks to the DateTime parameter. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `long fromLastUpdated` [parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) and [cast to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10276324/6384980) independently

```
[Route("api/v1/Product/{site}/{start?}/{pageSize?}/{from?}")]
public IHttpActionResult Product(Site site, int start = 1, int pageSize = 100, long? fromLastUpdated = null)
{
    if (fromLastUpdated.HasValue)
    {
        var ticks = fromLastUpdated.Value;
        var time = new TimeSpan(fromLastUpdated);
        var dateTime = new DateTime() + time;
        // ...
    }
    return ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can call it with the following route *v1/Product/2/1/1000/2016-11-17T01:37:57.4700000*. The model binding will work properly.
2. Or you can define a custom model binder:

   ```
   public class DateTimeModelBinder : System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.IModelBinder
   {
       public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
       {
           if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(DateTime?)) return false;

           long result;

           if  (!long.TryParse(actionContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["from"].ToString(), out result)) 
               return false;

           bindingContext.Model = new DateTime(result);

           return bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid;
       }
   }

   [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
   [Route("api/v1/Product/{site}/{start?}/{pageSize?}/{from?}")]
   public IHttpActionResult Product(Site site, 
                                    int start = 1, 
                                    int pageSize = 100,
                                    [System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderAttribute(typeof(DateTimeModelBinder))] DateTime? fromLastUpdated = null)   
   {
       // your code
   }
   ```